# Why does numpy.median scale so well?

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity

A question I recently got at a job interview, was:

```
Write a data structure that supports two operations.
1. Adding a number to the structure.
2. Calculating the median.
The operations to add a number and calculate the median must have a minimum time complexity.
```

My implementation was pretty simple, basically keep the elements sorted, this way adding an elements costs O(log(n)) instead of O(1), but the median is O(1) instead of O(n*log(n))

I also added an implementation that is naive, but contains the elements in a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, random
import math
from time import time

class MedianList():
    def __init__(self, initial_values = []):
        self.values = sorted(initial_values)
        self.size = len(initial_values)

    def add_element(self, element):
        index = self.find_pos(self.values, element)
        self.values = self.values[:index] + [element] + self.values[index:]
        self.size += 1

    def find_pos(self, values, element):
        if len(values) == 0: return 0
        index = int(len(values)/2)
        if element > values[index]: 
            return self.find_pos(values[index+1:], element) + index +  1
        if element < values[index]:
            return self.find_pos(values[:index], element)
        if element == values[index]: return index

    def median(self):
        if self.size == 0: return np.nan
        split = math.floor(self.size/2)
        if self.size % 2 == 1:
            return self.values[split]
        try:
            return (self.values[split] + self.values[split-1])/2
        except:
            print(self.values, self.size, split)

class NaiveMedianList():
    def __init__(self, initial_values = []):
        self.values = sorted(initial_values)

    def add_element(self, element):
        self.values.append(element)

    def median(self):
        split = math.floor(len(self.values)/2)
        sorted_values = sorted(self.values)
        if len(self.values) % 2 == 1:
            return sorted_values[split]
        return (sorted_values[split] + sorted_values[split-1])/2

class NumpyMedianList():
    def __init__(self, initial_values = []):
        self.values = np.array(initial_values)

    def add_element(self, element):
        self.values = np.append(self.values, element)

    def median(self):
        return np.median(self.values)

def time_performance(median_list, total_elements = 10**5):
    elements = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(total_elements)]
    times = []
    start = time()
    for element in elements:
        median_list.add_element(element)
        median_list.median()
        times.append(time() - start)
    return times

ml_times = time_performance(MedianList())
nl_times = time_performance(NaiveMedianList())
npl_times = time_performance(NumpyMedianList())
times = pd.DataFrame()
times['MedianList'] = ml_times
times['NaiveMedianList'] = nl_times
times['NumpyMedianList'] = npl_times
times.plot()
plt.show()
```

And here is how the performances look, for 10^4 elements:
[image]

And for 10^5 elements, the naive numpy implementation is actually faster:

[image]

My question is:
How come? Even if numpy is faster by a constant factor, how is their median function scaling so well, if they do not keep a sorted version of the array?

Comment: There are algorithms that can find the median in linear time, O(n), even for unsorted arrays. [Here is one reference](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/median/): do a web search for "fast median algorithm" for others. Numpy probably uses a variation on one of those. It is not necessary to sort the list before finding the median, though that is the naïve algorithm.

Comment: one should also have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Variants as it is related

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks a lot, that answers my question.

Comment: Would a simple binary tree not be optimal? O(logn) insert+balance and O(1) for retrieval?

Comment: @David Is it O(1) for retrieval? Isn't it O(log(n))?

Comment: If you make a small tweak of allowing the root node to hold one or two numbers depending on if you have an odd number of numbers or not, then the retrieval only needs to look at the root node which would be O(1).

Comment: @David you're right. I think a sorted list is equivalent to binary tree in this problem though? That means that even with the O(n) median function, the numpy version should scale worse. I guess numpy just has a huge constant advantage.

Comment: The sorted list is not equivalent to a binary tree in this example. It takes O(n) time to insert into the list versus O(logn) for insert in the tree.

Comment: @HristoBuyukliev I like your systematic approach to achieve an O(1) target operation cost for the search for a median value -- **would you mind to also add to graph also values measured for the native `numpy` `.median()` method**, called on a ready-to-go `numpy.array` of pre-generated numbers, i.e. **without skewing readings** with also including into measured section all TimeDOMAIN costs of building a respective list-alike representation and the iterator loop. Also would be reasonable to benchmark only on the out of in-cache list/array sizes ... 1E7, 1E8 ... right? **That is fair, isn't it?**

Answer (score 7):

We can inspect the Numpy source code for `median` ([source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6914bb41f0fb3c1ba500bae4e7d671da9536786f/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4037-L4123)):

```
def median(a, axis=None, out=None, overwrite_input=False, keepdims=False):
    ...

    if overwrite_input:
        if axis is None:
            part = a.ravel()
            part.partition(kth)
        else:
            a.partition(kth, axis=axis)
            part = a
    else:
        part = partition(a, kth, axis=axis)

...
```

The key function is `partition`, which from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html), uses [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect). As @zython commented, this is a variant of [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Variants), which provides the critical performance boost.